# Finding a regex match from an array of regexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def match_line regex
    @line.match(regex) if !regex.is_a?(Array)
    regex.each {|rgx| 
        results = @line.match(rgx) 
        return results if !results.nil? 
    }
    return nil
end
```

This looks like something that could be done in a one line idiomatic way, and I'm just not seeing how.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to see if one of the regex patterns in the array matches something? Or, do you want to find out which of the regex patterns matched?

Comment: You meant to put `return` before the second line, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[*regex].map{ |re| @line.match re }.compact.first
```

or

```
Array(regex).map{ |re| @line.match re }.compact.first
```

Comment: Thank you, that is great.  Does the Array() turn a variable into an array if it isn't already one?  Also, I assume all of the regexes are matched and there isn't a way to jump out after the first match?

Comment: nm on Array().. that's a very useful function.

Comment: That's correct, it will iterate over all regexes in regex, but assuming there are relatively few this won't be a big deal. You could do a custom each that short-circuits but I doubt the performance gain would be worth the loss in readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [*regex].find{|r| @line.match(r)}
 return $~ #will return the last MatchedData returned, otherwise nil.
```

`$~` will return the last MatchedData returned, otherwise nil.

Comment: :( perlish magic global variables are unreadable, as indicated by your explaining comment.

Comment: Having a comment associated with that line seems like no issue to me, especially because it is literally one line that is in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def match_line regex
  [*regex].each { |r| return r if (r = @line.match r) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a preferred, established practice to pass arguments in this case like

```
match_line(regex1, regex2, ...)
```

or

```
match_line(*array_of_regexes)
```

rather than

```
match_line([regex1, regex2, ...])
```

or

```
match_lines(array_of_regexes)
```

so your conditioning regarding array-ness is unnecessary.

```
def match_line *regex
  regex.detect{|r| @line =~ r}
  Regexp.last_match
end
```